# How to change location of staging bucket from Dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I created my Dataprep project but the staging bucket created by default is US located, when my source data is located in EU BigQuery tables.

For that difference in the regions, I'm getting an error when running a job.

Please, could you let me know how to change the default location of the staging bucket? Or how can I solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [change the Cloud Storage bucket/folders used by Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-dataprep#set_up) for uploads, job runs, and temp storage by making sure you have created a bucket in your desired [location](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations), selecting the icon which displays the first initial of the account owner's username located in the bottom left corner, then selecting "Settings" from the drop-down menu. It will bring you to the [User account's page](https://clouddataprep.com/settings) and there you will be able to replace the old bucket for the new one.